# Where is 3rd clutch pressure switch for Honda Accord 2000 sedan 2.3 litters engine?

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, accord

I am looking for locations of 3rd clutch pressure switch on Honda Accord 2000 sedan 2.3 litters engine. I struggled to find correct videos on youtube (some show 2nd clutch pressure switch, or 3rd clutch for 3.0 litters engine). I also could not find a diagram/manual of my transmission on internet neither. I know it looks like this <sub>(got this picture from autozone website)</sub>:

[image]

<sub>My google-foo is not working. This place is my last hope. Thanks.</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  I would bet it's going to be the same as the 3L engine one ... you might want to check.